# Looking to Identify a connector, to engineer a solution using a USB connector

Tags: usb, identification, cables, rs232

I have been tasked with installing an NCR 76 (7876) Scanner/Scale in my grandfather's store. The device was purchased over mercadolibre.com and was not sent with documentation, but was supplied with some cables similar to this, without the splitting part:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/NCR-SPLITTER-CABLE-PN-497-0439684-NEW-IN-PACKAGE-FREE-SHIPPING-LOT-OF-10-CABLES/222763414231?epid=3011716892&hash=item33ddbbf2d7:g:wTEAAOSwqbxaOpe2

On that cable, one side has an RJ type modular conector called 10C10P and on the other side is the connector in question. The cabling follows the RS232 Standard.

Once I figure out what connector it is I can see how it reads data, and I can work on a solution where I change de conector to a USB interface, so that I can hook up the Scanner/Scale via USB to a PC.

Here is the User Guide: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n7yshrSeB5ulE-ajyHoGEf6zJtdGUfYz/view?usp=sharing

Thank you

Comment: that looks like a cable that is used by IBM on their cash registers

Comment: Does yours not have the USB interface built in - or does that not use a regular USB cable?

Comment: It comes with the USB interface, but I beleive that to use it, you do need a special cable

Answer (score 1):

looks like Shielded Data Link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shielded_data_link_connector

Comment: Wow, I searched for hours trying to find info out about it. Thank you